# how to create textbox in WinApi

Tags: winapi

I create like this

```
htextbox=CreateWindow(L"static",L"",WS_BORDER|ES_MULTILINE|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,50,0,
            100,50,hWnd,(HMENU)ID_STATIC,hInst,NULL);
```

But I can't write text there.
**What is wrong?**

Comment: Are you looking for an `edit` box? A "static" control, as its name implies, desn't let you type into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say that you want a text box which makes me think you want the user to be able to edit the text. In which case you have the wrong window class. The `STATIC` window class is for labels. What you want is an [`EDIT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485918.aspx) control.